# What's the name of film where aliens make earth better then blow it up

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm sure it was a 2 or 3 part film with Tom Cruise in it but I may be wrong. Aliens made the planet better with no war or hunger. The children born were more advanced, able to do telepathy etc. The aliens took the children off Earth to a better more advanced planet then, when everyone on Earth died, they blew it up.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: possibly see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153586/benevolent-aliens-who-initially-refuse-to-show-themselves (about the novel on which the proposed answer is based)

Answer (score 5):

Reminiscent of the miniseries [Childhood's End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childhood%27s_End_(miniseries)).

It was in three parts. No Tom Cruise though.

> Aliens made the planet better with no war or hunger.

Wikipedia says of part 2: *In 2035, life on Earth resembles a pastoral idyll.*

> The aliens took the children off Earth to a better more advanced
>   planet then, when everyone on Earth died, they blew it up.

Wikipedia says of part 3: *The Earth is destroyed as the children join the Overmind.*

Comment: I didn't know the book had been made into a miniseries. I have to see it.